# Is there a shortcut for validating a field only when it's present, in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I find myself doing this:

```
validates_numericality_of :mileage,:if => Proc.new {|car| car.mileage.present? }
```

Sometimes, the mileage field may not be sent, but when it is, I want it validated. I have no problem in having the Proc inside my code, but it's code which I'm kind of duplicating for all the other optional fields. Is there a shortcut like `:if => present?` ?
I'm using Rails 3.0.5.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out [:allow_nil](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html)

> :allow_nil - If set to true, skips
>   this validation if the attribute is
>   nil (default is false).

According to the API docs, empty strings are converted to nils before validation, so this should work in either case.

Comment: According to the docs, "Notice that for fixnum and float columns empty strings are converted to nil" so I think it works still

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [`before_validation`](http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html#M000064) hook to convert empty strings to `nil` and then use the [`:allow_nil` option to `validates_numericality_of`](http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#M000091):

```
before_validation :clean_up_milage # This would replace '' with nil
validates_numericality_of :milage, :allow_nil => true
```

Comment: allow_nil converts blanks to nil, so this isn't needed.